# Creating a SAP UI5 XML View with a Table bound to a JSON Model Array

Tags: xml, json, data-binding, sapui5

In one view controller I am capturing an event and using that to generate an Ajax call to retrieve additional data. This data is then stored as a JSONModel in the parent controller (id is "app"). This all works as expected and results in the following JSON model:

```
var jsonText = ...
sap.ui.getCore().byId("app").setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(jsonText), "theProject");
```

Using console.log, the example data in that model is:

```
{
    "Id":"29",
    "AccountId":"28",
    "Account":"Test Account",
    "Name":"Test Project",
    "ExpensePercentage":"0",
    "FixedBid":"95400.00",
    "Complete":"false",
    "Calculated":"95400.00",
    "Billed":"7917.50",
    "Invoices":[
        {
            "Id":"17",
            "Number":"LE02042015",
            "Date":"02/04/2015",
            "Services":"7762.50",
            "Expenses":"1220.33"
        },
        {
            "Id":"18",
            "Number":"LE02042015A",
            "Date":"02/04/2015",
            "Services":"155.00",
            "Expenses":"824.70"
        }
    ]
}
```

Everything is as desired to this point. I then navigate to a secondary view to display this information. The main data elements are displayed in the ObjectHeader, then I have an IconTabBar, with a single IconTabFilter and inside that a table to display the Invoices array. It is with the array and getting it bound to the Table that I am having an issue. Below is the XML view being used to display this data:

```
<core:View 
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form"
controllerName="linxas.com.fiori.application.view.Project" 
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<Page title="Project Summary"
      showNavButton="true"
      navButtonPress="handleNavButtonPress">
    <ObjectHeader
        title="{theProject>/Name}"
        number="{theProject>/Calculated}"
        numberUnit="USD" >
        <attributes>
            <ObjectAttribute text="Account: {theProject>/Account}" />
            <ObjectAttribute text="Fixed Bid: {theProject>/FixedBid}" />
        </attributes>
        <firstStatus>
            <ObjectStatus id="projectStatus"
                text="{
                    path: 'theProject>/Complete',
                    formatter: 'linxas.com.fiori.application.util.Formatter.statusText'
                }"
                state="{
                    path: 'theProject>/Complete',
                    formatter: 'linxas.com.fiori.application.util.Formatter.statusState'
                }" 
            />
        </firstStatus>
    </ObjectHeader>
    <IconTabBar expanded="true" select="handleTabSelection">
        <items>
            <IconTabFilter icon="sap-icon://sales-order">
                <Table
                    headerText="Invoices"
                    items="{theProject>/Invoices}">
                    <columns>
                        <Column>
                            <header>
                                <Label text="Invoice No." />
                            </header>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <header>
                                <Label text="Date" />
                            </header>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <header>
                                <Label text="Services" />
                            </header>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <header>
                                <Label text="Expenses" />
                            </header>
                        </Column>
                    </columns>
                    <ColumnListItem type="Inactive">
                        <cells>
                            <ObjectIdentifier title="{Number}" />
                            <Text
                                text="{
                                    path:'Date'
                                }" 
                            />
                            <Text
                                text="{
                                    path:'Services'
                                }" 
                            />
                            <Text
                                text="{
                                    path:'Expenses'
                                }" 
                            />
                        </cells>
                    </ColumnListItem>
                </Table>
            </IconTabFilter>
        </items>
    </IconTabBar>
    <footer>
        <Bar>
        </Bar>
    </footer>
</Page>
```

What I get is a successful header section with all the proper data displayed, as well as the tab and table. The table has in it the correct number of rows, but all cells are empty, as if my binding to the aggregation was correct, but the binding to the individual properties are not correct. This seems like it should be very simple, yet I am having a tough time with this one.

UPDATE:

herrlock's comment below solved my problem. I need to reference the model name in the cell controls as well. I thought that since the model reference had been made in the table itself, it would not need to be made again in the tables items. That was an incorrect assumption.

So the fixed view looks like:

```
<core:View 
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form"
controllerName="linxas.com.fiori.application.view.Project" 
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<Page title="Project Summary"
      showNavButton="true"
      navButtonPress="handleNavButtonPress">
    <ObjectHeader
        title="{theProject>/Name}"
        number="{theProject>/Calculated}"
        numberUnit="USD" >
        <attributes>
            <ObjectAttribute text="Account: {theProject>/Account}" />
            <ObjectAttribute text="Fixed Bid: {theProject>/FixedBid}" />
        </attributes>
        <firstStatus>
            <ObjectStatus id="projectStatus"
                text="{
                    path: 'theProject>/Complete',
                    formatter: 'linxas.com.fiori.application.util.Formatter.statusText'
                }"
                state="{
                    path: 'theProject>/Complete',
                    formatter: 'linxas.com.fiori.application.util.Formatter.statusState'
                }" 
            />
        </firstStatus>
    </ObjectHeader>
    <IconTabBar expanded="true" select="handleTabSelection">
        <items>
            <IconTabFilter icon="sap-icon://sales-order">
                <Table
                    headerText="Invoices"
                    items="{theProject>/Invoices}">
                    <columns>
                        <Column>
                            <header>
                                <Label text="Invoice No." />
                            </header>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <header>
                                <Label text="Date" />
                            </header>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <header>
                                <Label text="Services" />
                            </header>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <header>
                                <Label text="Expenses" />
                            </header>
                        </Column>
                    </columns>
                    <ColumnListItem type="Inactive">
                        <cells>
                            <ObjectIdentifier title="{theProject>Number}" />
                            <Text
                                text="{
                                    path:'theProject>Date'
                                }" 
                            />
                            <Text
                                text="{
                                    path:'theProject>Services'
                                }" 
                            />
                            <Text
                                text="{
                                    path:'theProject>Expenses'
                                }" 
                            />
                        </cells>
                    </ColumnListItem>
                </Table>
            </IconTabFilter>
        </items>
    </IconTabBar>
    <footer>
        <Bar>
        </Bar>
    </footer>
</Page>
```

Thanks!

Comment: try `path:'theProject>Date'` instead of `path:'Date'` in your first Text

Comment: Thanks @herrlock, that did the trick. I thought I had actually tried that already, but apparently needed to clear my browser cache before it showed the changes in the page.